# Is "to treat" a proper synonym for "to handle (an event)" or "to process (some information)" or "to perform (some work)"

Tags: word-usage, translation

As a French programmer, it always bothers me when I see my colleagues name functions like `treatSomeEvent()` or `treatReport()`, when I would prefer `handleSomeEvent()` or `processReport()`.

To my understanding, "to treat" is more synonym with "to discuss" or "to ponder". Also, I have never found this expression in native-English litterature.

On the other hand, [online resources](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/treat) just indicate that "to treat" means:

> to deal with or think about (something) especially in a particular way

... and therefore the use of this verb might be correct.

In French, the verb "traiter", while rather vague, is acceptable in both cases. Does "to treat some event" (so as to take a decision) or "to treat some information" (so as to record it) or "to treat an order" (so as to fulfill the mission) sound natural to a native English speaker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand your concern and agree with you: **treat** cannot be used in the same sense as one would use **handle** or **process**. As specified in your definition, an important element is **in a particular way**: it implies some sort of attitude to the object, which *must be specified*.

Thus, it would be perfectly acceptable to name a procedure **treatReportWithDisdain()** or **treatEventWithoutAnySenseOfUrgency()** - assuming that there were ever a need to write such routines- but it would not be OK to name a procedure **treatReport()** or **treatEvent()**.

Comment: I agree, I would find such naming confusing. One can **treat** wood, by apply a preservative, one can treat a friend to a meal, but I would never simply say to someone "I shall treat your application for a loan."